# Measuring power factor on sinusoids

Tags: sampling, power-factor-correction, power-measurement

I'm not sure if this is the best forum for this or whether stackoverflow mightn't be better, but I'll ask here and see what people think.

I have a system measuring 50Hz voltage and currents at 1kHz.  I'm using quadrature demodulation to measure the phase shift and calculating `cos(φ)` from that, and also calculating the active and RMS power and inferring `cos(φ)` from them.  These calculations are done over one-second slices of the data.

I'll attach example Python code below but basically the method looks like this:

- Multiply the instantaneous voltage and current timeseries together to get instantaneous power, `p_inst`.
- Integrate `p_inst` (using a trapezoidal integration) and divide by the time length of the data slice to get the active power, `p_act`.
- Square each sample in `p_inst`, take the average of `p_inst**2` across the timeseries and then take the square root of that value to get the RMS power, `p_rms`.
- Calculate the power factor, `pf = p_act / p_rms`.
- Using a zero-crossing-detection method, estimate the frequency of the voltage signal.
- Generate quadrature reference signals at that frequency (ie `cos(2πft)`, `sin(2πft)`).
- Multiply the voltage by each of the reference signals and integrate (again a trapezoidal approximation) each of the resulting timeseries, resulting in `v_cos` and `v_sin`.  The phase angle of the voltage signal, `v_phi`, relative to some arbitrary reference, is then `atan2(v_sin, v_cos)`.
- Repeat the previous step for the current.  The phase lag of the current relative to the voltage is then `φ = v_phi - i_phi`.
- My second estimate of the power factor is then `cos(φ)`.

For a sinusoidal signal with 30 degrees phase lag, the correct `cos(φ)` is approximately 0.86602540378443871.  The quadrature demodulation method produces a very good approximation, 0.86636025346085943.  But the ratio-of-powers method produces a very wrong estimate - 0.77542956418409648.  This is equivalent to nearly ten degrees error in the phase angle.

I assumed at first that I'd got the quadrature demodulation wrong (being the more complex calculation) but it produces the right answer.  I then assumed that the signal was badly non-sinusoidal and that this would explain the difference - but the code below does the same calculation on ideal sinusoids.

What have I got wrong here?

Full Python code demonstrating the problem:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

t = np.arange(0, 600, 0.001)
t_rad = 2 * np.pi * 50 * t
phi = 30 * np.pi / 180

v = 230 * np.sin(t_rad)
i = 200 * np.sin(t_rad + phi)

p_inst = v * i

data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([t, v, i, p_inst]).transpose(), columns=['t', 'v', 'i', 'p_inst'], index=t)

def gen_act(x):
    return np.trapz(x.p_inst, x=x.index) / (x.index[-1] - x.index[0])

def gen_rms(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(x.p_inst**2))

second_bins = data.groupby(lambda x: int(x))
p_act = second_bins.apply(gen_act)
p_rms = second_bins.apply(gen_rms)

def estimate_frequency(t, v):
    t = t.values
    v = v.values
    try:
        zero_crossings = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(v)) > 0.5)[0]
        diffs = np.diff(t[zero_crossings])
        accum_intervals = np.copy(diffs)
        accum_interval = 0
        ii = 0
        for ii in range(len(accum_intervals)):
            accum_interval += diffs[ii]
            accum_intervals[ii] = accum_interval
            if accum_interval >= 0.01:
                accum_interval = 0

        zero_crossings = zero_crossings[np.hstack([np.where(accum_intervals > 0.01)[0], -1])]
        ends = zero_crossings[[0, -1]]
        frequency = (len(zero_crossings) - 1) / (t[ends[1]] - t[ends[0]])
        return frequency
    except:
        return float('NaN')

def generate_reference_signals(t, f):
    freq = np.mean(f)
    if np.isnan(freq):
        return None
    x = t * 2 * np.pi * freq
    return np.sin(x), np.cos(x)

def estimate_phi(t, v, i, refs):
    def angle_from_refs(t, x, refs):
        s_i = np.trapz(x * refs[0], t)
        c_i = np.trapz(x * refs[1], t)
        return np.arctan2(c_i, s_i)

    angle = angle_from_refs(t, i, refs) - angle_from_refs(t, v, refs)
    while angle > np.pi:
        angle -= 2*np.pi
    return angle

def gen_phi(x):
    f = estimate_frequency(x.t, x.v)
    refs = generate_reference_signals(x.t, f)
    return estimate_phi(x.t, x.v, x.i, refs)

phi = second_bins.apply(gen_phi)
cos_phi = np.cos(phi)
pf = p_act / p_rms

print('Power factor estimated from quadrature demodulation: {}'.format(np.mean(cos_phi)))
print('Power factor estimated from measured power: {}'.format(np.mean(pf)))
print('True power factor: {}'.format(np.cos(30 * np.pi / 180)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third step, squaring `p_inst`, is incorrect.

What you really want is to find the RMS values of the sets of voltage and current samples separately, yielding `v_rms` and `i_rms`, and then multiply those results together to get `p_rms`.

Comment: Ergh, aren't they the same thing?

Comment: No, they are not, and that's the whole point.

Comment: In my defence, the bug is one I inherited.  But I should have spotted it.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a naming issue, which once more proves how important is using correct  vocabulary in technical matters.

You say you are after RMS power, then your original algorithm is ok since given N instantaneous power samples

$$P_\text{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{N}p_k^2}$$

the above is just applying the definition of Root of Mean of Squares.

Now the point is RMS power is a mostly useless quantity and definitevely  not what you need to work  out power factor.

What you should have computed is apparent power instead, often designed by capital S, and [S]=VA.

One possible generalisation of apparent power which works well even with non sinusoidal distorted currents and voltages simply states that

$$S=V_\text{RMS}\;I_\text{RMS}$$

and also, calling Pact the average, i.e. active power
$$P_\text{act}=\text{PF}\;S\quad\Rightarrow\quad \text{PF}=\frac{P_\text{act}}{S}=\frac{P_\text{act}}{V_\text{RMS}I_\text{RMS}}$$

Note that power factor \$\text{PF}=\cos\varphi\$ in case of sinusoidal quantities but also includes non linear effects in case there are some.